# How can i use my system login credential as alfresco?

Tags: alfresco

I need to map my system login as the login for alfresco , so the user can login to alfresco without creating a separate login in alfresco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to add suitable ldap-ad authentication subsystem & configure the ldap-synchronisation - here is an example:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/tasks/auth-example-oneldap-ad.html

More details regarding ldap-ad authentication subsystems in Alfresco:
http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/auth-ldap-intro.html

If your're searching for NTLM or kerberos related SSO then you'll have to configure this additionally to the config I've mentioned before ...
Take a look here: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/auth-kerberos-intro.html

Comment: No, I need the windows login credential to be used as the login to the alfresco. The user will be able to login to alfresco using his windows login credential. Eg: The sam\User1 is the windows login, the same should be the login for alfresco

Comment: Okay I have a few doubt in that 
`passthru.authentication.defaultAdministratorUserNames=<Your.Active.Directory.Administrator.Account>` what should I give here
`ldap.synchronization.groupSearchBase=cn\=users,dc=<company.domain>,dc=com` and here